# Using Jackson, how do you unmarshal JSON to a Java Map, but have a specific nested member as a domain instance?

Tags: java, json, jackson, unmarshalling, domain-model

Given the following example JSON:

```
{
  "aud": "you",
  "exp": 1300819380,
  "user": {
    "name": "Joe",
    "address": {
        "street": "1234 Main Street",
        "city": "Anytown",
        "state": "CA",
        "postalCode": 94401
    }
  }
}
```

and the Java interface:

```
public interface Deserializer {
    Map<String,Object> deserialize(String json);
}
```

Using Jackson, how do I implement `deserialize` such that it returns a map of name/value pairs, but converts just the `user` field into a Java `User` domain object such that the following is possible:

```
Map<String,Object> map = deserializer.deserialize(json);
assert map.get("user") instanceof User;
```

The idea is that the top-level name/value pairs can be anything and are unstructured and we don't want to force a domain model.  But if a `user` member exists, we *do* want that member value to be unmarshalled into a `User` domain instance.

Additionally, if possible, I *really* don't want to have to modify the `deserialize` implementation if the `User` domain model changes (e.g. if a field is added or removed over time).

Answer (score 1):

> Using Jackson, how do I implement `deserialize` such that it returns a map of name/value pairs, but converts just the user field into a Java `User` domain object [...]

One *possible* way to do it without writing custom deserializers would be:

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> deserialize(String json) throws IOException {

    Map<String, Object> map =
            mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

    Optional<Object> optional = Optional.ofNullable(map.get("user"));
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
        User user = mapper.convertValue(optional.get(), User.class);
        map.put("user", user);
    }

    return map;
}
```

If the `user` property is present in the JSON, it's mapped to a `User` instance and then replaced in the map.